# What is the difference adding view directly without following code

Tags: coronasdk, corona-storyboard

```
function main()

    display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar ) 

    mainGroup:insert(director.directorView)

    director:changeScene("titlescreen")
end
```

I'v not used this code instead directly called

director:changeScene ( "splash" )

its running but then why we do the above coding.

Answer (score 0):

1. `display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)` is used to change the appearance of the status bar. You can see more [here](http://jp.anscamobile.com/dev/reference/index/displaysetstatusbar/index.html).
2. `mainGroup:insert(director.directorView)` is of adding the group from director class. And this implies that `director view` is used as master page. [See more...](http://crossplatformmobileapp.wordpress.com/2013/04/11/page-transition-using-director-class-in-crossplatform-app-with-corona/)
3. `director:changeScene("sceneName"`) is used to the transition between scenes.

As you said, the code will work without the 1st and 2nd lines, but when you come back to the page from next page, it may cause director error.

Keep coding... :)